Manhwa where the main character goes to another world and participates in a game in which regular people have to escape from five people in a city
I'm looking for a manhwa where the main character (MC) goes to another world and participates in a game in which regular people have to escape from five people in a city.
The MC has black skinny hair and gets a thief system that makes it easier for him and he just plays with them while running away. The first power he got was to run fast.
A system is like a game panel or a blue tab floating in the air that only the MC can see. This is like a wheel of fortune.
The powers I remember are super speed, parkour, pickpocketing, disguise and martial arts.

Welcome to SciFi.SE. As someone not familiar with manga in general could you possibly [edit] to describe what a system is? What did it look like? Why does it make things easier for him?

I'm unclear on what you mean by a thief system (specifically, the 'thief' part). Elsewhere in your description, you stated that the first power the MC got was to run fast, so did his system enable him to steal or copy other people's powers? And if so, do you recall any of the other powers he stole or copied?

@LogicDictates Most likely it's a thief (or rogue) in the video game sense, as in a character class that is fast, agile, and/or hard to detect. There's not necessarily any stealing involved.

@qazmlpok - I was confused by the final line of the current revision of the question, but rereading it (and allowing for what I think are a couple of typos), it sounds like you're probably right.

@St.iv - I edited your question to clean up what I believe were some typos. If I made any mistakes, please edit the question yourself to fix them.
